# Flutter: Does it matter what code is in setState()?

Tags: dart, state, flutter, setstate

When we want a StatefulWidget to rebuild we call `setState()` but does it really matter if the code we type is inside that function or outside of it?

Is this:

```
class _ShoppingListState extends State<ShoppingList> {
  Set<Product> _shoppingCart = new Set<Product>();
  void _handleCartChanged(Product product, bool inCart) {
    setState(() {
      if (inCart)
        _shoppingCart.add(product);
      else
        _shoppingCart.remove(product);
    });
  }
}
```

the same as this:

```
class _ShoppingListState extends State<ShoppingList> {
  Set<Product> _shoppingCart = new Set<Product>();
  void _handleCartChanged(Product product, bool inCart) {
    if (inCart)
      _shoppingCart.add(product);
    else
      _shoppingCart.remove(product);
    });
    setState((){});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should do all your mutations *inside* the closure, and the computing outside of the closure.

Comment: It _is_ part of the API guarantee that setState is called immediately,  the recommendation to only do mutations inside is for readability purposes.

Answer (score 18):

According to the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html):

> ```
> @protected
>
> void setState (
>     VoidCallback fn
> )
> ```
>
> Notify the framework that the internal state of this object has
>   changed.
>
> Whenever you change the internal state of a State object, make the
>   change in a function that you pass to setState:
>
> `setState(() { _myState = newValue });`
>
> The provided callback is immediately called synchronously. It must not
>   return a future (the callback cannot be async), since then it would be
>   unclear when the state was actually being set.

And also

> Generally it is recommended that the setState method only be used to
>   wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might
>   be associated with the change.

It's doesn't explicitly say any thing about if it's different to call is in or outside the function. But it does recommend to put it inside. And in my opinion it's also more readable and logical if you put the changes in side the `setState` function